# How can I draw these circuits in LTspice?

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice

I am new to electronic circuits and I don't know how to draw these circuits. I can draw some basic closed circuits but I never understood these open ones. Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thank you.

[image]
I tried to draw the first circuit the best way I can, and it looks like this:

[image]
My try at the second circuit:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to just draw these schematics in LTspice, or do you also want to simulate them?  I think you did a good job drawing them.  Maybe just relabel `D` to `Ideal` so it matches the textbook better.

Comment: Pascal, from where did you take that diagram?

Comment: Add a voltage source Vi to the left of the first circuit. Idem for other.

Comment: @SteKulov I am supposed to simulate the output signals by supplying the input signal to the circuits given in the graph. How can I supply the input signal to circuits? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @periblepsis My university teacher gave me some practice exercises to prepare for my exam.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't really 'open' circuits, they are closed circuits drawn with the labels 'closing' the circuits through some assumed external components.

Your drawing of those fragments is fine. However, if you want to simulate them, you'll need to add all of the sources that have been left out.

I've also shown where voltage measurement takes place with a meter symbol. In LTSPICE, those don't need to be shown, you can just probe there. However showing the measurement point can be useful for documentation purposes, and is required in some other simulators.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgNrZu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In circuit (a), you have an input voltage Vi applied and an output voltage measured differentially to the circuit. That will work fine in real life, but for a simulator, you need to add a ground connection, to tell it which node to treat as 0 V, and to use as the reference for all other nodes. Any node will do for this, but most people tend to use the lowest voltage node, or the node that's drawn physically lowest on the page. For usual schematic drawing conventions, that's usually the same node.

In circuit (b), the existence of single-ended labels like +5 V mean these are to be treated with respect to a ground.

Answer (score 1):

You need to gain a little more familiarity with LTspice if you want to closely mimic those diagrams. You may also do just as well with less familiarity. But then it won't look exactly the same. Let me illustrate.

Here's a complete, functioning example that looks a lot like your case:

[image]

I added some `pretty boxes` around each section, given them names. Just as an extra bonus.

There is some `extra` stuff down in the lower-left corner that is needed to specify a ***transient*** run (time), to specify what exactly an **IDEAL** diode does (see the .MODEL directive), and to provide your \$+5\:\text{V}\$ source node. But it otherwise is a close analog to your problem.

However, it also involves some other nuances. \$V_1\$ has to use **PULSE**, which is an advanced method, to generate your \$V_I\$ source. Also, in order to keep the labels, I used a jumper. All this does is connect one node label to another one.

You could do all of the above with less:

[image]

But then it doesn't look quite the same, anymore. It is. But it just isn't as obvious.

Note that the above requires you to understand ideas like node labels (use the F4 function key to start creating one), how to define an **IDEAL** diode model and the meaning of the parameters it uses, what a ***transient run*** is, and be able to read a diagram of the input source to construct an appropriate type of voltage source.

Everything takes some knowledge. You develop it step by step as you encounter problems that present some new challenges to overcome. No way around that fact.